# SMS not received on new Android

Tags: sms, ios

I just purchased a new Moto G Power (Android version 10) and replaced my old iPhone 6s backup phone. When I put the Sim card in, everything worked except incoming SMS. Outgoing SMS worked fine, just not incoming. I figured it might be related to the Apple account and iMessage, so I found a [link](https://selfsolve.apple.com/deregister-imessage/) that would disconnect from iMessage. I saw on a website that it might take a few hours to take effect, so I was patient about it.

That happened yesterday afternoon (around 3 PM). It's quite a few hours later and I am still not receiving incoming SMS on my device. When I put the Sim card in the iPhone messages come in, and they come in as SMS rather than iMessages. So I'm not sure why it's not going to the Android device.

Does anyone have any recommendations for next steps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to reach out to your carrier's support team...

If you can send SMS and make/receive calls, then the issue likely isn't with your device. SMS uses the same transport and registration as is used for phone calls, so this likely falls on your carrier.

This has occasionally been an issue with some carriers when users are switching from Apple to Android, and a new SIM has to be issued sometimes.

Reaching out and working with the carrier's support team is probably best at this point.